# How to work with related tables in the Gridview : Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, model, yii2, relation

I've written my code like this:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'quantity',
        [
            'header' => 'SN',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data) {
                $product = Product::findOne($data->product_ID);
                return $product->SN_required ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' : '';
            }
        ],
```

In order to show it like this:

[image]

Yet I think this is not correct (eventho it's working). Could someone please give me the correct notation for this sort of code?

I know this has to do with the model relations. That has been changed in Yii2.

```
 public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), ['ID' => 'product_ID']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. You can access relations inside the closure using `$data->relation` in your case:

```
'value' => function($data) {
    return $data->product->SN_required ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' : '';
}
```

You can view the [Yii2 page on working with relations in data widgets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations) for more information.

Comment: Unless you want to see the actual text of "<span...." You will need to add ' 'format' => 'raw', '  It works great, Thanks!